# How to get value from applicationSettings?

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, windows, web-reference

I am trying to get value of service in my application from app.config. I have to send it to the application which shows the URL. A web service which I am consuming in this aplication also using it so can not move it to appSettings.

I want to get this value '**http://192.168.4.22:82/Service.asmx**' through c# code.

```
<applicationSettings>
    <SDHSServer.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="DOServer_WebReference1_Service" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://192.168.4.22:82/Service.asmx</value>
      </setting>
    </SDHSServer.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
```

Comment: [System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx)

Comment: Or in a [more strongly typed manner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx). Worked with ASP.NET app but don't think there is big difference.

Comment: Your snippet above shows the setting you're trying to get is already *in* the appSettings, which you said you didn't want to do. Which is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure i get the question,

```
string s = SDHSServer.Properties.Settings.DOServer_WebReference1_Service;
```

will get you it

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly you have two Visual Studio C# projects. The first (project A) has a setting you want to access in the second (project B). To do that you have to perform the following steps:

- Add a reference from project B to project A
- Change the access modifier of the settings i project A to public (default is internal)

  [image: Visual Studio settings editor]
- Now you can access the setting in project B, in your case using the fully qualified name `SDHSServer.Properties.Settings.Default.DOServer_WebReference1_Service`

Note that in the settings editor you can set a value for the setting. This is the default value for the setting and this value is also stored in the `App.config` file for the project. However, you can override this value by providing another value in the `App.config` file for the application executing.

In this example, the `App.config` file for project A will contain the value for the setting which is `http://192.168.4.22:82/Service.asmx`. However, you can override this in the `App.config` file for project B to get another value. That is probably not what you want to do but you should be aware of this.

Comment: Thumbs up for mentioning the fact that you need to set the access modifier of the settings to public in order to access it.

Answer (score 4):

I use this code in a ASP.Net 4.0 site to pull section data out of the 'applicationsetting' section:

```
public sealed class SiteSupport {


    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve specific section value from the web.config
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="configSection">Main Web.config section</param>
    /// <param name="subSection">Child Section{One layer down}</param>
    /// <param name="innersection">Keyed on Section Name</param>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Element property name</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <example>string setting = NoordWorld.Common.Utilities.SiteSupport.RetrieveApplicationSetting("applicationSettings", "NoordWorld.ServiceSite.Properties.Settings", "ServiceWS_SrvWebReference_Service", "value")</example>
    public static string RetrieveApplicationSetting(string configSection, string subSection, string innersection, string propertyName) {
        string result = string.Empty;
        HttpWorkerRequest fakeWorkerRequest = null;
        try {
            using (TextWriter textWriter = new StringWriter()) {
                fakeWorkerRequest = new SimpleWorkerRequest("default.aspx", "", textWriter);
                var fakeHTTPContext = new HttpContext(fakeWorkerRequest);
                Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(new ExeConfigurationFileMap() { ExeConfigFilename = fakeHTTPContext.Server.MapPath(@"~/Web.config") }, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
                ConfigurationSectionGroup group = config.SectionGroups[configSection];
                if (group != null) {
                    ClientSettingsSection clientSection = group.Sections[subSection] as ClientSettingsSection;
                    if (clientSection != null) {
                        SettingElement settingElement = clientSection.Settings.Get(innersection);
                        if (settingElement != null) {
                            result = (((SettingValueElement)(settingElement.ElementInformation.Properties[propertyName].Value)).ValueXml).InnerText;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            fakeWorkerRequest.CloseConnection();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

> https://www.ServiceWS.com/webservices/Golf

Answer (score 0):

Depends something like this.

```
  var s = SDHSServer.Properties.Settings.Default.DOServer_WebReference1_Service;
```

or

```
  var s = SDHSServer.Properties.Settings.DOServer_WebReference1_Service;
```